# Specialized Search Query Refinement for Auto-Complete function

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a query for an autocomplete function on a mysql table that has many instances of similar titles, generally things like different years, such as '2010 Chevrolet Lumina' or 'Chevrolet Lumina 2009', etc.

The query I am currently using is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('$mystring') LIMIT 10", $db);
```

The $mystring variable gets built as folows:

```
$queryString = addslashes($_REQUEST['queryString']);
if(strlen($queryString) > 0) {
  $array = explode(' ',  $queryString);
  foreach($array as $var){
    $ctr++;
    if($ctr == '1'){
      $mystring = '"' . $var . '"';
    }
    else {
      $mystring .= ' "' . $var . '"';
    }
  }
}
```

What I need to be able to do is somehow group things so only one version of a very similar actually shows in the autosuggest dropdown, leaving room for other products with chevrolet in them as well. Currently it is showing all 10 spots filled with the same product with different years, options, etc.

This one should give some of you brainiacs a good workout  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to create a new field on the products table, something like *classification*. All the models would be entered with the same classification (e.g. "Chevrolet"). You could then still MATCH AGAINST *name*, but GROUP BY *classification*. Assuming you are using MySQL you can cheat a little and get away with selecting values and matching against values that you are not grouping by. Technically in SQL this gives undefined results and many SQL engines will not even let you try to do this, but MySQL lets you do it -- and it returns a more-or-less random sample that matches. So, for example, if you did the above query, grouped by classification, only one model (picked pretty much at random) will show up in the auto-completer.

Comment: Hmm the database is 1 million plus entries and there is no way, easily, of breaking them down far enough into classifications or 'brands' for your method. Other ideas?

Comment: Well if there is no easy way to break it down even *with* an additional column, I really can't imagine there is an easy way to break it down *without* a secondary column. What is your criteria for considering names "very similar"? I think you have to come up with a clear definition of that first.

Comment: Say the person types in the word 'ipod' the autocomplete tends to spit out a selection of ipod accessories culled from hundreds of possibles, many of which are basically the same things such as ear buds, or accessory kits, because of the sheer number of these, most times the actual Ipods won't show in the list.

Comment: I understand the problem in the abstract, but that's too vague to make an implementation. I think you will have to come up with a programmatic way to group similar items (and I'd recommend using a utility column to store these groups by a key). *Without a programmatic way to distinguish "similar" product names from "different" product names, there is no way to do what you want regardless of the implementation method*. Without actually looking at the data set, it's hard to say what the best way to separate this is.

Comment: One possibility is to run a script that reads in every product name in the database, splitting each name into word tokens, and then counting the number of times each word token appears. Then, for each product, if any of the words match a high-frequency token (say 10 times or more), set the classification column to equal the token that appears most often. If no words in a product are overall high-frequency, set the classification column equal to the product name. Then use group-by as described above.

Comment: Trying the 'brand/classification' idea by running a database of most major brand names against the database to see what kind of coverage across the board it gets. If it covers enough of the database, then the group by should do wonders.

Comment: Ben: drop william a note at nucz@mindspring.com when you get a chance please, he would like to talk to you about what we are doing.